# Will marking swift extension public change the property in the extension to be implicitly public or internal?

Tags: ios, swift

So in Apple documentation:

*Any type members added in an extension have the same default access level as type members declared in the original type being extended. If you extend a public or internal type, any new type members you add will have a default access level of **internal**.*

Giving a sub class of UIView extension:

```
extension UIViewSubClass
{
    var helloWorld : String {
        get {
            return "helloWorld"
        }
    }
}
```

This will mark `helloWorld` as internal, I have no problem, and I cannot see it in my Objective-C based project.

However, if I mark the extension to be public:

```
public extension UIViewSubClass
{
    var helloWorld : String {
        get {
            return "helloWorld"
        }
    }
}
```

Now `helloWorld` apprears in my Objective-C based code, which means it is marked as public.

However, I don't see Apple mentions this, did it?

I just saw the documentation said a public class will still has implicit internal level.

```
public class SomePublicClass {          // explicitly public class
    public var somePublicProperty = 0    // explicitly public class member
    var someInternalProperty = 0         // implicitly internal class member
    private func somePrivateMethod() {}  // explicitly private class member
}
```

Marking public for extension seems have different effect than marking a Class definition. This makes me confused.

Could someone help me, is this supposed to be so, or this is a sort of swift bug? I am with swift 2.1 and Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Answer:** Yes, placing access level modifiers (in your case, `public`, specifically) in front of extensions modify the *default access level of all new types in the scope of that extension*.

Note that the modifier does not affect the access level of the class/struct/etc being extended (only its members). However, there are things that ought to be considered, as I will discuss below.

---

In this discussion, I'll post a few important facts regarding regarding access levels in Swift. All these are from the [Swift Language Guide - Access Control - Access Levels](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html).

Let's first assure what you've already stated:

> All entities in your code (with a few specific exceptions, as
> described later in this chapter) have a default access level of
> **internal** if you do not specify an explicit access level yourself.

OK, this goes in line with what you've quoted in you question: any *new* type members, whether in a class or structure definition, will have a *default* access level of internal.

Now, lets look at the **access level modifier** that you can add in front of extensions:

> You can extend a class, structure, or enumeration in any access
> context in which the class, structure, or enumeration is available.
> Any type members added in an extension have the same default access
> level as type members declared in the original type being extended. *If
> you extend a public or internal type, any new type members you add
> will have a **default access level of internal**. If you extend a private
> type, any new type members you add will have a **default access level of
> private**.*
>
> Alternatively, you can mark an extension with an **explicit access level
> modifier** (for example, private extension) to set a **new default access
> level for all members defined within the extension**. This new default
> can still be overridden within the extension for individual type
> members.

This sorts things out. We look at your example, and assume that your class `UIViewSubClass` has access level `public` (or compile time error, se below):

```
/* no access level modifier: default access level will be 'internal' */
extension UIViewSubClass
{
    // default access level used: internal
    var helloWorld : String { 
        get {
            return "helloWorld"
        }
    }
}

// modify default access level to public
public extension UIViewSubClass
{
    // default access level used: public
    var helloWorld : String { 
        get {
            return "helloWorld"
        }
    }
}
```

With the discussion above in mind, it's expected that your `helloWorld` in you `public extension ...` is marked as `internal`, as this is, in this context, the default access level. In the context of extensions, access level modifiers work differently than when applied to types.

Finally, we should point out that using a `public` access modifier when extending a non-public class will yield a compile time error in Swift. So in your case above:

- If `UISubViewClass` is an `internal` or a `private` class, then the `public extension ...` on the class will yield an compile time error.
- If `UISubViewClass` is a `public` class, then adding the `public extension` will be redundant as the default access modifier of a public class is already, by definition, `public`.

I'd say that the error described above is not really an error to avoid runtime errors, but rather to avoid redundant (and confusing) code: `public` member types or `private` or `internal` classes will never make use of its `public` access level.

```
class MyImplicitlyInternalClass {
    private var myExplicitlyPrivateVar = 0
    var myImplicitlyInternalVar = 0
    public var myExplicitlyPublicVar = 0 // warning, see (Note 1) below
        // redundant 'public': can never be accessed publicly
        // myExplicitlyPublicVar will behave as 'internal'
}

public extension MyImplicitlyInternalClass { // error, see (Note 2)
    var myNewVarIsInternal : Int { get { return 0 } } 
}
/* (Note 1) Compile type warning:
        "Declaring a public var for an internal class."

   (Note 2) Compile time error:
        "Extension of internal class cannot be declared public." 

   Summary: in theory, these two above are the same type of
            'faults', but only the latter is flagged as and error. */
```

Hence, it only ever makes sense to use the access level modifiers on extensions to *make the default access level more restrictive*, i.e., using `internal extension ...` of a `public` class, or `private extension` or an `internal` class.

Comment: I missed the paragrash of `Alternatively, you can mark an extension with an explicit access level modifier`.. Thanks for this detailed answer! BTW, I saw your another post about inout :) well done, you are good at swift details pal!

Comment: @Wingzero I can understand the you did, I think that some subject in the Swift language guide is sometimes a bit to "spread out" (covered with different theory in difference sections). Anyway, happy to help, I'm learning by helping myself!